# Improper Integral of $\log(x)$

Tags: integration, logarithms, improper-integrals

What is the integral of $\log(x)$ from $0$ to infinity? I have found that it is $h \cdot (\log(h)-1)$ for $h > 0$, however I am not sure about it, because in my textbook I do not have similiar results to integrals like this one (most of them are equal to infinity or diverge). I used limits in order to solve this.

Comment: Considering $\log(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$, this is going to diverge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since, for $k>1$,
$$
\int_1^{k}\log x\,dx=k(\log k-1)+1
$$
we have
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_1^{k}\log x\,dx=\infty
$$
Similarly, for $0<h<1$,
$$
\int_{h}^1\log x\,dx=-h(\log h-1)-1
$$
we have
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\int_{h}^1\log x\,dx=-1
$$
The improper integral
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\log x\,dx
$$
doesn't converge.

Comment: So the integral is equal to ∞?

Comment: @M.Papapetros If you prefer to say so.